# Render Partial Page from Action Method in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-7.0

How can I render "PartialViewResult" output for an Action Method without an Ajax/Query. Need to Render the Partial page along with Main page loading but as an output of an Action Method.
Is it possible in ASP.NET Core 6 or 7?

ASP.NET Core 6 seems not longer supports this? Something similar to RenderAction()? Is ViewComponent is only way?

Comment: Do you mean `return new  PartialViewResult(){ViewName = "xxx",};` in action method?If so,it can work in .net6.

Comment: Yes same..., but I need to call the Action Method from Razor Page without Ajax. Method like - <partial name>, @await Html.RenderPartialAsync - works with cshtml pages not with controller Actions right?

Comment: Yes,if you want to render the partial view in your view,you need to use html helper like <partial name>, @await Html.RenderPartialAsync,and there is no need to  set action method for the partial view.

Comment: `RenderAction()` and `Action()` are not available in .Net core, IF you want a action method to load a partial view, you need to use view component or use ajax to access the action. Or if you don't need a action to load view, You can use partial view directly.

Comment: Did you find any better solution than ViewComponent?
As I am stuck in the same situation where my .net 4.8 mvc app has master view having tabs to render different views from different controller actions. But now, I might need to convert everything to view component... but not sure if other actions in all the different controller(s) will work the same way or not? So strange that they have removed this helper method!